# How to deal with Maybe type in Haskell list comprehensions

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming

I have a list comprehension in Haskell that specifies a predicate on a Maybe type:

`[x | x <- listOfMaybes, isJust(f y), x == fromJust(f y)]`

is there a way to simplify this expression?

Comment: Please provide a fully working example. Without `<-`, this is not a list comprehension and I doubt it compiles.

Comment: updated the code snippet

Comment: I think the `x==fromJust(f y)` in the list comprehension isn't necessary. Conditioning on `isJust(f y)` does the job.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you simply want to filter out all the `Nothing`s, shang's answer gives the most concise solution. However, it can be done easily in a list comprehension:

```
[x | Just x <- f y]
```

Comment: You might want to explain that this is essentially `flip concatMap (f y) $ \result -> case result of {Just x -> [x]; {-Implicitly added!-} _ -> []}`

Comment: Right, I find it easier to just learn that pattern matching in list comprehensions is perfectly valid and automatically filters out non-matching cases. Your desugaring is not exactly adding clarity, I find :-)

Comment: interesting that the behaviour is different here from pattern matching in do notation where `Just x <- f y` might error

Comment: It wouldn't be different to do notation, because it's the monad instance of List that controls how pattern matching errors are handled. And in List, error simply is ignored. This might have changed recently due to the MonadFail proposal, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 15):

You can simply use [`catMaybes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes) (from [`Data.Maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Data-Maybe.html)) to filter out all `Nothing` values.